# Extracting ByteBuffer from GenericRecord sometimes has extra values

Tags: scala, avro

I serialise objects to avro format in spark. These objects include byte arrays (edit: [polylines](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm), which are represented as strings). When I inspect the file, the data is correct.

```
$ java -jar ~/data/avro-tools-1.8.1.jar tojson part-00000.avro | grep 123
{"key":123, "data":{"bytes":"gt_upA`mjrcE{Cw^uBwY"}}
# ^ this example has been simplified for this question
```

`` gt_upA`mjrcE{Cw^uBwY `` is the correct string representation of the byte array.

I then try to deserialise these files in my plain Scala app. Most values are parsed correctly, but sometimes there are extra bytes in the parsed arrays.

```
val entity: GenericRecord
val byteBuffer = entity.get("data").asInstanceOf[ByteBuffer]
println(new String(byteBuffer.array, "UTF-8"))
```

Results in `` gt_upA`mjrcE{Cw^uBwYB ``. Note the extra trailing `B`.

I am parsing the files in parallel, and I guess that the ByteBuffer instance is not thread safe and backing arrays are being overwritten.

How should I be parsing these files?

edit: While the question stands, I have since encoded the values as UTF-8 strings directly. It adds additional work when parsing, but avoids the problems with ByteBuffer's inability to be read concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

you can't print arbitrary binary data as UTF-8. Some byte combinations are invalid or ambiguous, and converting them to characters isn't well defined, and depends on the library you are using (and also on your terminal setting).

Just print them as hexademicals instead:

```
byteBuffer.array.foreach { b => print("%02X".format(b)) }
println
```

Comment: Good point. However, these values are polylines and are printable by definition.